# Cocos2d and interface building options

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

After a few years with cocos2d, i have to say the truth ,i am seek of putting `CCMenus` in code, order them, create `CCScenes` to every page with coding, especially when i see the simple way its done with `Apple's storyboards` .

I know that the `cocos2d interface builder project` was shut down(they say so in the site) , so i wonder what are my ways , to work with cocos2d to order scene/buttons and storyboards ,but not do it all by coding (coding the coordinates,buttons,pages,scrollers,etc) .

Is there an option for me that i haven't heard about ??

(i use the cocos2d v2.0)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [SpriteBuilder](http://www.spritebuilder.com/) (an amazing open source project forked off CocosBuilder).

Comment: Thanks, but i will tell you whats the problem with it, that a developer CANT move-on every day to another platform that pops up . cocos2d has a community of millions of developers, they can't just jump everyday to a new one, so not only that i have to learn it from the start, i am again depends on that platform to be good, or not . and because cocos2d is great, i can't just leave 2 years of experience ...

Comment: Continuously improving your tools and techniques is important and there is no harm in learning or evaluating them. As for SpriteBuilder, its just a tool 'developed for cocos2d-iphone' and that in my opinion can greatly help you in reducing your development time.

Comment: Also SpriteBuilder is a direct descendant of CocosBuilder which I presume you meant by "interface builder project"? Though SpriteBuilder is currently a very early version, possibly not in a usable state, and intended for v3 (I don't know whether it can or will support v2). There were two others (CocoShop, ??) but they've been long abandoned. Alternative is LevelHelper.

Comment: thanks, so how for example, you guys use cocos2d to order your menus ? do you code their positions, and actually do coding for each scene ?